# 'Controversial' Ordering

Tags: statistics

This is *seemingly* simple question that naturally fell into the ambit of my attention recently. And it's oddly *reflexively referential* in a certain way also.

On a certain *webforum* that I frequent (not this one - a *far far* less 'respectable' one than this one ... but *not **4chan***, I hasten to add! (in fact *4chan* doesn't *have* any votes - there wouldn't be any point, as *everyone's* score would just go to $-\infty$ within a few minutes!)), there are several options for listing the posts: there is one that does it by nett voting-score; a chronological one (these are pretty obvious ones to have): but there is another one designated 'controversial'. I wrote to the moderator asking what this ordering means, and he replied saying that it's puts a premium on a post according as it has a large number of both upvotes *and* downvotes. My instantaneous thought was "that's simple enough" ... but then I went on to think ... "but *exactly what* formula *would you use*?".

I have decided eventually that, if I were writing the code for the forum, I would use $$\sqrt{m^2+n^2}\operatorname{atn}\frac{2mn}{|m^2-n^2|} ,$$ with $m$ & $n$ being the vote-numbers - *whichever-whichever*. (It *begs* normalisation by a $2/\pi$ ... but that doesn't matter if it's just for the sake of comparison.) The reasoning is that this recipe is proportional to the magnitude of the vote 'vector', but scaled by the *angle* by which it departs from either comprising purely upvotes or purely downvotes. It looks ridiculously complicated for such a simple thing ... but then it's all on computer: & what is calculating *that* compared to image-processing, & stuff like that.

And I wonder whether anyone could *either* suggest something else, or tell me what coders of web-fora *actually use*.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what coders of web fora actually use, but I'd say the simplest formula would be to just use the product of up- and downvotes, or if linear scaling with the total number of votes is considered important, the geometric mean (that is, the square root of the product).

This is because for a given sum (that is, a given total number of votes), the product is maximal when the number of up- and downvotes are equal, and falls down to zero when one of them goes to zero (a post that has all its vote in one direction clearly is not controversial at all).

Moreover, the product has the advantage that it is simple, which means less chance of implementation bugs, and fast, which means you won't have it as performance bottleneck even for large numbers of posts.

If you want your rating not *purely* on how controversial it is, you can also use something like
$$m-n + c\sqrt{mn}$$
where $c$ tells how much being controversial should be weighted; c=0 would be ordering purely after score (that is, number of positive minus number of negative votes, like e.g. here on Stack Exchange), a large value for $c$ would mean that being highly controversial is the main sorting criterion.

Comment: Yes - mine is probably overly _fussy_, insisting that it be exactly proportional to the product of the magnitude of the 'vector' and the lesser of its angular departures from the axes. But as for implementation bugs, _atn_ is so elementary a function, I'm not sure that would really be an issue. But then ... I suppose it just might be. I think you would _need_ to take the square root though - as you said - the _geometric_ mean, rather than just use the product, to keep a rudimentary quasiproportionality to the magnitude of the vector ¶ And of course, thanks for your contribution.

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey: As long as it only for ordering, the square root doesn't matter because it is a strictly monotonous growing function, which means it is order-preserving. The square root only matters if you want to display something like a “controversality score” that for constant vote ratio is proportional to the number of votes. As of possible implementation bugs; the first thin I notice is that your formula as given doesn't work for $m=n$ (equal number of up- and downvotes), so that case would have to be special cased; forgetting or mishandling special cases is a common source of bugs.

Comment: This would lead to some strange incentives - like if a post had many upvotes and no downvotes, you could give one downvote to hugely increase the total score.

Comment: @JairTaylor: A post that has no downvotes clearly is completely uncontroversial, don't you think? And if anyone wants to optimize the controversality rank, by the very definition of it a vote in minority direction would increase that rank more than a vote in majority direction, no matter which exact function you choose for ordering.

Comment: @celtschk -- I admit it did slip from my mind that it's safe orderingwise not to take the square root, even over a two-variable function - obviously now you mention it. ¶ The zero i think wouldn't matter - depends how rudimentary the coding language is, whether you use the _atn2_ function as it's often called, whether the language 'accomodates' the division by zero with an _infinity_ flag. ¶ And what was that someone's just said about possible pathological behaviours - part of the reason I suggested my rather complicated (but with a simple _logic_ to it) formula is robustitude that way.

Comment: Infact - and I'm actually inspired here by what you pointed out about the square-root not mattering _orderingwise_ - you could use √(m²+n²)atn(min(m,n)/max(m,n)) - which _is thoroughly_ robust. So I _certainly_ agree that my original recipe was overcomplicated in _that_ respect! But then - _both_ m & n could be zero!

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey: Note that for the special case of $m=n=0$, even an `atan2` won't save you from a special case, as there both numerator and denominator are zero.

Comment: But then if they are _both_ zero, then _that_ special case is easier to handle - without an error - especially as it might be flagged for other reasons in the forum also. ¶ Please do keep in mind that I am not _bent on_ advancing my formula as _the definitive_ one!

Comment: I do think my function is a bit safer at the _extreme edges_, also: _definitely_ taking the square-rooted form of your function this time so that we are comparing functions 'normalised' to _r_: a single contrary vote at a post that already has a high score in one direction (say q, to mean either m or n) would cause a hike (from 0) of √q by your recipe, but only of ≐ 1 by mine ... & the latter seems to me more what it ought to be.

Comment: I'll just say one more thing & then I'll be through - I think what's going on here is that we are weighing two different approaches against each other: one (mine) that takes an elementary _logic_ - in this case 'product of magnitude' & angle & says "we implement _this_ logic, even at the cost of the resulting expression ending-up complicated"; and the other (in this instance yours), which is to be governed by how robust and-or simple _the mathematics __itself___ shall be. I've faced this dilemma often in my own coding adventures; and I'm sure it must be acknowledged in industry - _named_ even!

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey: Note that I amended the answer.

Comment: @celtschk -- glad you sent a comment - I might well have missed that. ¶ This discussion might possibly be said to be part of 'measure theory' ... I think they call it? It can be a fascinating subject, the use of arbitrary functions & measures - sometimes parametrised: the Yukawa potential; the repulsive 1/r^12 term in the Lennard-Jones potential: I devised one myself recently for normalising thr Rutherford scattering distribution. It could be made quite a rigorous department, I think - you would want to somehow measure the 'sensitivity' of the consequences to the 'arbitrarity' - that sort of